# How to compress an image to be small?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to compress an image from size 5 mb to just over 200kb using React Native.

I have not tried any form yet, because I did not find anything of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `react-native-image-crop-picker` and combine it to redux

for example :

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  width: 300, // set your values
  height: 400,
  cropping: true //if you want enable to crop or not
}).then(image => {
  console.log(image);
});
```